# How to remotely shut down running tasks with Tokio

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a UDP socket that is receiving data

```
pub async fn start()  -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    loop {
        let mut data  = vec![0; 1024];
        socket.recv_from(&mut data).await?;
    }
}
```

This code is currently blocked on the `.await` when there is no data coming in. I want to gracefully shut down my server from my main thread, so how do I send a signal to this `.await` that it should stop sleeping and shut down instead?

Comment: You can use [`tokio::select`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.22/tokio/macro.select.html) to wait for data and a shutdown signal (for which you can use [`tokio:: broadcast`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.22/tokio/sync/broadcast/index.html)) at the same time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Note:** The Tokio website has a page on [graceful shutdown](https://tokio.rs/tokio/topics/shutdown).

If you have more than one task to kill, you should use a [broadcast channel](https://docs.rs/tokio/1/tokio/sync/broadcast/index.html) to send shutdown messages. You can use it together with [`tokio::select!`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1/tokio/macro.select.html).

```
use tokio::sync::broadcast::Receiver;

// You may want to log errors rather than return them in this function.
pub async fn start(kill: Receiver<()>) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    tokio::select! {
        output = real_start() => output,
        _ = kill.recv() => Err(...),
    }
}

pub async fn real_start() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    loop {
        let mut data  = vec![0; 1024];
        socket.recv_from(&mut data).await?;
    }
}
```

Then to kill all the tasks, send a message on the channel.

---

To kill only a single task, you can use the [`JoinHandle::abort`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1/tokio/task/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.abort) method, which will kill the task as soon as possible. Note that this method is available only in Tokio 1.x and 0.3.x, and to abort a task using Tokio 0.2.x, see the next section below.

```
let task = tokio::spawn(start());

...

task.abort();
```

---

As an alternative to `JoinHandle::abort`, you can use [`abortable`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/future/fn.abortable.html) from the futures crate. When you spawn the task, you do the following:

```
let (task, handle) = abortable(start());
tokio::spawn(task);
```

Then later you can kill the task by calling the `abort` method.

```
handle.abort();
```

Of course, a channel with `select!` can also be used to kill a single task, perhaps combined with an [`oneshot`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1/tokio/sync/oneshot/index.html) channel rather than a broadcast channel.

---

All of these methods guarantee that the `real_start` method is killed at an `.await`. It is not possible to kill the task while it is running code between two `.await`s. You can read more about why this is [here](https://ryhl.io/blog/async-what-is-blocking/).

The [mini-redis](https://github.com/tokio-rs/mini-redis/) project contains an accessible real-world example of graceful shutdown of a server. Additionally, the Tokio tutorial has chapters on both [select](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/select) and [channels](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/channels).