# Is there a way to make StreamExt::next non blocking (fail fast) if the stream is empty (need to wait for the next element)?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Currently I am doing something like this

```
use tokio::time::timeout;

while let Ok(option_element) = timeout(Duration::from_nanos(1), stream.next()).await {
...
}
```

to drain the items already in the rx buffer of the stream. I don't want to wait for the next element that has not been received.

I think the timeout would slow down the while loop.

I am wondering that is there a better way to do this without the use of the timeout?
Possibly like this https://github.com/async-rs/async-std/issues/579 but for the streams in futures/tokio.

Comment: Are you doing other work as well in the `while` loop? I'm kind of assuming so, since you don't want to wait for the stream. If so, it seems more reasonable to just make two futures with `async` blocks (one for the loop and one for the other work) and just join them, instead of having a more complex "non-blocking" loop.

Comment: I am manipulating a user space TCP Socket (non async/await style) in the while loop. I am doing this because I need a kind of back pressure so the data from upstream won't blow up the tx buffer of the TCP Socket.

Comment: Then that seems more like the real problem here, I think. You're not really allowed to have proper (non-async) blocking code inside async code, you should instead be using asynchronous TCP streams (e.g. from [tokio](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.6/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html) or [async-std](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.8.0/async_std/net/struct.TcpStream.html)) when working with asynchronous code.

Comment: The TCP Socket doesn't block the loop. It just send the data to a channel. The upstream is tokio's TcpStream. The TCP Socket is face to the tunnel file (VPN). I break the while loop when the tx buffer of the TCP Socket is full.

Comment: The purpose of this `while` loop is to fill the tx buffer of the TCP Socket as possible and don't block the outer main loop that reads ip packets from the tunnel file. If the other side of the tunnel ack TCP packets slowly it can pass pressure to the upstream to make it produce data slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is to use the [`FutureExt::now_or_never`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.now_or_never) method from the futures crate as in `stream.next().now_or_never()`.

However it is important to avoid writing a busy loop that waits on several things by calling `now_or_never` on each thing in a loop. This is bad because it is blocking the thread, and you should prefer a different solution such as [`tokio::select!`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.select.html) to wait for multiple things. For the special case of this where you are constantly checking whether the task should shut down, see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64084955/) instead.

On the other hand, an example where using `now_or_never` is perfectly fine is when you want to empty a queue for the items available now so you can batch process them in some manner. This is fine because the `now_or_never` loop will stop spinning as soon as it has emptied the queue.

Beware that if the stream is empty, then `now_or_never` *will* succeed because `next()` immediately returns `None` in this case.

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem. I found that the `futures::select_biased!` can also solve this problem but the `FutureExt::now_or_never` is much better for this.